# Singleton returning empty Object

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

We have a cache implementation in our project, for which we have used singleton design pattern. Class Cache is a singleton class which has a `HashMap<String,HashMap> m` inside it. Sometime when we get data from the `Hashmap m` . returned inner HashMap is empty. This is happening randomly and we are clueless why it is happening. We have ensured in our code that there is no remove statement is invoked on map, as well as no code is present which is removing this data.

Any leads on this will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Cache Class :-

```
public Class Cache
{
    public static Cache c;
    private HashMap<String,HashMap> m ;
    private Cache()
    {
         m = new HashMap<String,HashMap>();
    }
    public static synchronized Cache getInstance()
    {
        if(c == null) { c = new Cache(); }
        return c;
    }
    public void put(String id,HashMap value)
    {    m.put(id,value);     }
    public HashMap get(String id)
    {    return m.get(id);    }
}
```

Code to put value :-

```
Cache c = Cache.getInstance();
c.put("CITY_CACHE",cityMap);// cityMap is a non empty map having city data
```

Code to get Value:-

```
Cache c = Cache.getInstance();
HashMap cityMap = c.get("CITY_CACHE");
//city Map here becomes empty sometimes
```

This scenario occurring randomly in production and we are not able to replicate in Non production environment. I am suspecting it because of GC but have no evidence to prove it.

Comment: Lack of (possibly necessary) synchronization? (you're using a `HashMap`).

Comment: yes. without seeing any code, or without knowing anything about your project, this will be super-easy to answer. guess what: your inner Hashmap is empty. if you want to know why: re-examine the flow of your code and actions

Comment: Updated the post for better understanding, Thanks

Comment: The code given is not enough.  You need to figure out where other code also calls `c.put("CITY_CACHE",cityMap)` and overwrites the entry.  Also, if `Cache#put` and `Cache#get` are not `synchronized` you could have a race condition.

Comment: put is called from a synchronized wrapper class method which gets data from db and prepare cityMap

Answer (score 2):

While you synchronize getting the `Cache` instance, you don't protect the inner map's manipulation. You should either synchronize these operations or use a thread-safe map implementation, such as [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. We tried it too. Results are same.

Comment: @NishantModi Did u find the solution for that ?

Comment: No, not yet, we just added a workaround that hen it is empty reload it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have complete background of your project, I can suggest you some debugging steps. I don't think issue is due to synchronization. It might be possible that some part of your code is deleting the data before you get the same data (and this situation might happen with or without syncronization).

**Print the map data in log when you find no data with you key. Check that data is present on not in log?** Obviously we can not doubt on get method of Hashmap in java :)

and yes GC might be the reason too.

Comment: Can you help more on GC part

Comment: @NishantModi You can run your java application using Following parameter and capture the GC logs and check stop time for GC in logs. Also log the detail when get no data in map. and compare the timing of the both the logs.

-XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:<gc-log-file-path>

To understand the GC log. https://plumbr.io/blog/garbage-collection/understanding-garbage-collection-logs